# Why this tag don't appear in developer history top X%

Tags: support, bug, tags, developer-story

I was looking at the tag [react-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-context) and in the top user [Shubham Khatri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri)
 doesn't have that tag on top 1% on his developer history.

I also looked at other developer history and looks like nobody have it.

Why? Is that a bug or is an expected behavior?

Comment: Other tags outrank it in score I guess.

Comment: @Zoe what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't actually a bug.

The developer story lets you pick which top tags to show. As an example, here's mine:

> [image]

Which results in:

> [image]

And, as you can see, the unselected Firebase tag isn't included in the list.

The owner of the developer profile you used as an example probably didn't pick the react-context tag for whatever reasons they may have (and I can't give you an answer to those reasons).

Comment: Now everything makes sense, thanks!